# Как правильно настроить gunicorn для django проекта?

Tags: django, gunicorn

Я установил gunicorn, создал конфиг gunicorn_config.py:

```
command = '/root/code/mysite/env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/usr/bin/python3'
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = 3
user = 'root'
limit_request_fields = 32000
limit_request_field_size = 0
raw_env = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main.settings'
```

А так же скрипт bin/start_gunicorn.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/code/mysite/env/bin/activate
source /root/code/mysite/env/bin/postactivate
exec gunicorn  -c "/root/code/mysite/gunicorn_config.py" main.wsgi
```

При первом запуске этого скрипта все заработало(хоть и не совсем как надо):

```
bin/start_gunicorn.sh:source:3: no such file or directory: /root/code/mysite/env/bin/postactivate
[2020-12-27 00:47:03 +0300] [14568] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-12-27 00:47:03 +0300] [14568] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (14568)
[2020-12-27 00:47:03 +0300] [14568] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-12-27 00:47:03 +0300] [14700] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14700
[2020-12-27 00:47:03 +0300] [14701] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14701
[2020-12-27 00:47:04 +0300] [14702] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14702
```

Но в settings.py был некорректно указан путь `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, из-за чего не подгрузились все static файлы:

```
Not Found: /static/css/style.css
Not Found: /static/js/main.js
Not Found: /static/img/map.png
Not Found: /static/img/Check_mark1.png
Not Found: /static/img/call.png
```

После этого я исправил ошибку в пути, но теперь не могу запустить gunicorn:

```
bin/start_gunicorn.sh:source:3: no such file or directory: /root/code/mysite/env/bin/postactivate
[2020-12-27 00:59:29 +0300] [17006] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-12-27 00:59:29 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-12-27 00:59:29 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-12-27 00:59:30 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-12-27 00:59:30 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-12-27 00:59:31 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-12-27 00:59:31 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-12-27 00:59:32 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-12-27 00:59:32 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-12-27 00:59:33 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2020-12-27 00:59:33 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2020-12-27 00:59:34 +0300] [17006] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то, что у вас где-то запущен второй gunicorn

Comment: И как мне отключить второй? @andreymal